# Override a function in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, overriding

I'd like to override a function in the jQuery mobile library.  This is the function I want to override:

```
$navbar.delegate( "a", "vclick", function( event ) {
        if ( !$(event.target).hasClass( "ui-disabled" ) ) {
            $navbtns.removeClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
            $( this ).addClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
        }
    });
```

I can change the source code but what I'd prefer to do is add a function override in my code so when we upgrade jQuery mobile we won't forget and lose the change.

$navbar.delegate is encased in:

```
(function( $, undefined ) {

$.widget( "mobile.navbar", $.mobile.widget, {...
```

and I'm not really sure which variable to get to in order to change the function.

I tried just overriding $navbar.delegate but that didn't work.  I think that $navbar is a variable defined in the _create function of the $.widget function.

Might be too buried into the $.widget function to override without changing the source.  Any jQuery masters have ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The specific event handler that you are mentioning, is included in the `_create` jQuery Mobile method which is responsible for setting up the initial `navbar` widget display.

**Approach 1:**

You may use the `mobileinit` event bind to override the default settings of jQuery Mobile. Since the mobileinit event is triggered immediately, you need to bind your event handler before jQuery Mobile is loaded. In the event handler you can override the `$.mobile.navbar.prototype._create` method. The original implementation of the `navbar _create` method is copied apart from the piece of code you are mentioning. That code has been commented out.

Sample Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>jQuery Mobile Override Function Example</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            $(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){

              $.mobile.navbar.prototype._create = function() {

                    var $navbar = this.element,
                        $navbtns = $navbar.find( "a" ),
                        iconpos = $navbtns.filter( ":jqmData(icon)" ).length ?
                                                this.options.iconpos : undefined;

                    $navbar.addClass( "ui-navbar ui-mini" )
                        .attr( "role","navigation" )
                        .find( "ul" )
                        .jqmEnhanceable()
                        .grid({ grid: this.options.grid });

                    $navbtns.buttonMarkup({
                        corners:    false,
                        shadow:     false,
                        inline:     true,
                        iconpos:    iconpos
                    });

                    /*
                    $navbar.delegate( "a", "vclick", function( event ) {
                        if( !$(event.target).hasClass("ui-disabled") ) {
                            $navbtns.removeClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
                            $( this ).addClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
                        }
                    });
                    */

                    // Buttons in the navbar with ui-state-persist class should regain their active state before page show
                    $navbar.closest( ".ui-page" ).bind( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
                        $navbtns.filter( ".ui-state-persist" ).addClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
                    });
                };

            });

        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>jQuery Mobile Override Example</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Approach 2:**

You may use the following piece of code in order to override the whole `_create` method. Using this way you can customize the original implementation:

```
(function($){
    // reference to the original method
    var _old = $.mobile.navbar.prototype._create;

    $.mobile.navbar.prototype._create = function() {

        // put your custom code here
        // .....

        // in case you want to apply the default behaviour
        // return _old.apply(this);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Below you can find a working example. The original implementation of the `navbar _create` method is copied apart from the piece of code you are mentioning. That code has been commented out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>jQuery Mobile Override Function Example</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            (function($){

                // store original reference to the method
                var _old = $.mobile.navbar.prototype._create;

                $.mobile.navbar.prototype._create = function() {

                    var $navbar = this.element,
                        $navbtns = $navbar.find( "a" ),
                        iconpos = $navbtns.filter( ":jqmData(icon)" ).length ?
                                                this.options.iconpos : undefined;

                    $navbar.addClass( "ui-navbar ui-mini" )
                        .attr( "role","navigation" )
                        .find( "ul" )
                        .jqmEnhanceable()
                        .grid({ grid: this.options.grid });

                    $navbtns.buttonMarkup({
                        corners:    false,
                        shadow:     false,
                        inline:     true,
                        iconpos:    iconpos
                    });

                    /*
                    $navbar.delegate( "a", "vclick", function( event ) {
                        if( !$(event.target).hasClass("ui-disabled") ) {
                            $navbtns.removeClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
                            $( this ).addClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
                        }
                    });
                    */

                    // Buttons in the navbar with ui-state-persist class should regain their active state before page show
                    $navbar.closest( ".ui-page" ).bind( "pagebeforeshow", function() {
                        $navbtns.filter( ".ui-state-persist" ).addClass( $.mobile.activeBtnClass );
                    });
                };
            })(jQuery);

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>jQuery Mobile Override Example</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <div data-role="navbar">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">One</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Two</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```